# Resizing application window with JFrame and JPanel creates black space and tears, sometimes does not fit frame to panel properly

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel

Resizing application window creates black space and tears. I am a beginner programmer trying to create a simple chessboard that scales appropriately when you drag the borders of the window to resize. I was able to achieve this for the most part, however dragging the window creates a lot of artifacts and black space, and sometimes when releasing the mouse the frame does not properly fit the panel.

[Try it Yourself](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17xHYEM6Q79uhsJABeZL3ssnrH9dyIgOK?usp=sharing)

Source Code

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.ComponentListener;

public class Hello
{ 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            Board bd = new Board();
        });
        
    }
}

class ChessBoardPanel extends JPanel {
    private boolean white = false;
    public int cellSize;

    ChessBoardPanel(int chessBoardSize) {
        cellSize = chessBoardSize / 8;
    }
//draw the ChessBoard
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                if (white)
                    g.setColor(new Color(232, 191, 174));
                else
                    g.setColor(new Color(92, 52, 36));
                g.fillRect(i * cellSize, j * cellSize, cellSize, cellSize);
                white = !white;
            }
            white = !white;
        }
    }
}

class Board {
    int chessBoardSize = 512;
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chess Board");
    ChessBoardPanel panel = new ChessBoardPanel(chessBoardSize);
    //listens for when the application is resized
    ComponentAdapter ca = new ComponentAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            //resize panel by repainting
            Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
            chessBoardSize = frame.getSize().width - insets.left - insets.right;
            panel.cellSize = chessBoardSize / 8;
            panel.repaint();
            //fit frame to panel
            Dimension prefDimension = new Dimension(panel.cellSize * 8, panel.cellSize * 8);
            panel.setPreferredSize(prefDimension);
            frame.pack();
        };
    };
    
    Board() {
        frame.addComponentListener(ca);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Dimension prefDimension = new Dimension(panel.cellSize * 8, panel.cellSize * 8);
        panel.setPreferredSize(prefDimension);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        panel.repaint(); // Call repaint to trigger paintComponent
    }
}
```

My suspicion is that the problem lies within the Component Adapter where I set the preferred Dimensions to the dimensions of the chessboard and then re-pack the frame to fit the panel. I liked this idea because originally you could drag the width or height of the frame and it would create additional white space that I didn't want to see. If you see any egregious coding practices here feel free to educate me.

Comment: It only creates white space when its aspect ratio is too tall to remain square otherwise. It looks to me it does a rather good job. The only other thing you could do is to constrain to always square by using a resize listener